# Why am I not getting error Can't Perform React State Update on an Unmounted Error?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am currently learning React from book *React and React Native 4th Edition*.
In that I have doubt in topic *Cancelling requests and resetting state*.
It says

> There's a good chance that, at some point, your users will navigate your app and cause
> components to unmount before responses to their API requests arrive. When this
> happens, an error occurs because the component will attempt to update the state values of
> a component that has been removed.Thankfully, the useEffect() Hook has a mechanism to clean up things such as
> pending API requests when the component is removed.Let's take a look at an example of
> this in action:

This is the [Example](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/React-and-React-Native-4th-Edition/tree/main/Chapter04/cancelling-requests-and-resetting-state).
I just commented promise.cancel() as said to do in book (to see error).But i am not getting error?
[image]

Comment: Are you using React 18? React 18 no longer reports warnings of state updates on unmounted components. See https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/22114

Comment: Yeah, I am using react 18.

Comment: @DennisMartinez So in react 18,we do not need to clean up on unmount,am i right?

Comment: Yes, certain actions still warrant cleanup. For example, if you open a web socket connection, and then remove that component, what happens to that listener? It's still in memory until told otherwise, which warrants a cleanup on unmount. As for this particular example, if a promise is fulfilled and no component is mounted, it'll just ignore the response action. Before React 18, it used to throw a warning about a memory leak (if you did, say, setState on fulfillment), which they explain in the link I posted in my first comment.

Answer (score 1):

You are using **react 18** whitch has `Improved memory usage` now cleans up more internal fields on unmount, making the impact from unfixed memory leaks

Comment: So in react 18,we do not need to clean up on unmount,am i right?